# External CSS style is not applying if inline CSS is added

Tags: html, css, react-native, expo

External CSS stylesheet is not applying if I write inline and External CSS style together.

**The Stylesheet I have:**

```
const furStyles = StyleSheet.create({
title_text: {
        fontSize: 46,
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
      }
})
```

The below is the code where the problem occurs. Only **color:'#ED9780'** does work. The Stylesheet above does not apply at all if I add inline which is **{color:'#ED9780'}**.
The stylesheet is applied only if I delete inline styles in the bracket which is **{textAlign: 'center',color:'#ED9780'}**

```
<Text style={furStyles.title_text,{color:'#ED9780'}}>BEST</Text>
```

Why does this happen? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To combine (multiple) inline and stylesheet references in [Expo](https://docs.expo.dev/tutorial/text/) (React Native), you need to provide them in an array, for example:

```
// Notice that the only change to your code was adding square brackets `[]`
<Text style={[furStyles.title_text,{color:'#ED9780'}]}>BEST</Text>
```

Working Snack: https://snack.expo.dev/Coo98ohRQ

Source: https://freecontent.manning.com/applying-and-organizing-styles-in-react-native/

> It’s also possible to combine the two methodologies; specifying an
> array of styling properties using inline styles and references to
> stylesheets:
>
> style={[{color: 'black'}, styles.message]}

Answer (score 0):

Generally, inline styles are to be used as a last resort for this very reason. If a rule is specified in the inline `style` attribute, it takes precedence over all other styling that may be applied elsewhere, *unless* the `!important` keyword is used. You can read more about `!important` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#the_!important_exception), but you should avoid using it at (almost) all costs.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
<Text style={{...furStyles.title_text,color:'#ED9780'}}>BEST</Text>
```